# Determining the nullity of a linear map on $\mathbb R [ x ] _n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $ n \geqslant 3 $ and $ T : p(x) \rightarrow 6p(x) + p'(x) - x^2p''(x)$

You may assume that $T$ is linear. Determine the nullity of $T$.

Would you find the matrix representation of $T$ by applying $T$ to each of the basis vectors of $ \mathbb R [x]_n$ to find.

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}6 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ 0 & 6 & 2 & 0 & 0 & & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 6-2 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 6-6 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6-12 &  & 0 \\ \vdots & & & & & \ddots & n \\ 0 & \dots & & & & 0 & 6-n(n-1)\end{pmatrix} $$

Because this matrix is in echelon form, $A \underline v = \underline 0$ implies that $\underline v = \underline 0$, so the nullspace of $T = span\{ \underline 0 \}$

Hence the $nullity = dim\{ nullspace \} = 0$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is correct, but your reasoning is not actually. Please look at the 4th column, there is a zero at the diagonal. Since the matrix is triangular, this shows that determinant of this matrix is 0, hence the null space cannot be empty. It seems like this matrix has 1-dimensional null space, spanned by $24x^3-18x^2+6x-1$. You can find this polynomial from the 4*4 matrix on the upper left corner.

Comment: Thank-you! Would you be able to show me how you got the spanning polynomial?

Comment: Do you know how to find the null space of a matrix? You can either use that knowledge to find the null space of 4*4 matrix on the upper left corner, or start with an arbitrary polynomial of degree 3 $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ and solve T(p(x)=0 for a,b,c and d.

Comment: In this matrix, it is especially easy to solve the equation $$A \vec{v} = \vec{0}$$ as it is upper triangular. Consider using the method of back-substitution.

Comment: Thank-you again, I know how to find the nullspace of a matrix but I do not understand how finding the nullspace of the 4x4 matrix in the top left is sufficient to find the span of the whole matrix